# two terminals, one not showing processes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, command, ps

While I have two terminals open, when I run [program name] & in one terminal, why is it that when I then run ps on both terminals, only the one I have used to run the program shows the processes?

Answer (score 3):

See [`man ps`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)

> By default, `ps` selects all processes with the same effective user
> ID (euid=EUID) as the current user *and associated with the same
> terminal* as the invoker.

You are probably running the `ps` command in both terminals as the same user, but these are *two different terminals*. As the documentation states, `ps` will *by default*  only show processes associated with the same terminal.

You can see the ID of the terminal using the `tty` command.

To see processes associated with specific terminals, you could use option `-t`.

Comment: I don't understand, if it selected all with same ID why does one terminal recognise the program I opened and the other does not? Do you mean the second terminal differs in ID? What ID and how can I view the ID's of both? Also, does this have anything to do with TTY being different in each terminal

Comment: @honcho I did not write anything about a different user, but your processes are associated with different terminals.

Comment: Where does your definiton of ps come from? I feel like there is more of a reason and your mention of a EUID, where can I find this?

Comment: The text `man ps` in my answer is a command you can use on your system, and in my answer it is a link to an online version of a Linux manual page.

Comment: Each distinct username has a different UID. The `id` command shows this like `uid=1000(paul) gid=1000(paul) ...` followed by some other group information. Each terminal session is a controlling terminal for a group of processes that were initiated from it. If I am working on several tasks at once in different terminals, I only want each terminal  to tell me about its local tasks. There are other `ps` options that give the kind of report that a SysAdmin might need to look at all the activities on a system.

Comment: @honcho regarding EUID: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier

Comment: In both outputs you will see the shell process (bash or tcsh), it does not have the same pid, even if it has the same process name, what's the explanation for that?

Comment: You've got two `bash` (or `tcsh`) shells: one for each terminal. They're different instances so they get different PIDs